# How can I use the INCLUDE command in a specific place in my assembly code?

Tags: assembly, include

I am doing some code in Assembly but the code is more than 64K so I want to divide my main code into small codes,that I can add them in a specific place in my main code By the INCLUDE command. How can I do that?

Comment: You forgot to specify what assembler and environment you use. Also, `include` typically means source inclusion so doesn't have much to do with 64k limit which is presumably on the binary size.

Comment: using tasm DosBox